# Passing list of data from JSP to Set in Java

Tags: java, jsp, type-conversion, struts2, ognl

I use the Struts2 framework. In my action class I have a `Set<Item>` attribute with getters and setters:

```
private Set<Item> items;

public Set<Item> getItems()
{
    return items;
}

public void setItems(Set<Item> items)
{
    this.items = items;
}
```

On my JSP I have the following form:

```
<form action='...'>
    <input type="hidden" name="items.id" value="4592"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="items.id" value="5016"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="items.id" value="3227"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="items.id" value="8549"/>
</form>
```

I expected that form, when submitted to my action class, would result in a `Set<Item>` with 4 `Item` objects to be created and each of those Items would have their `Id` attribute set to the given value. However, when I run this,  the set is empty (no elements).

What's really strange is that my logging of this action:

> ACTIONCLASS - GET the set of items in action class
>   ACTIONCLASS - SET the set of item in action class
>   ACTIONCLASS - After setting the set, the set of items is EMPTY
>   ITEMCLASS - now creating a new ITEM object
>   ITEMCLASS - SET id of item to value: 4592
>   ITEMCLASS - now creating a new ITEM object
>   ITEMCLASS - SET id of item to value: 5016
>   ITEMCLASS - now creating a new ITEM object
>   ITEMCLASS - SET id of item to value: 3227
>   ITEMCLASS - now creating a new ITEM object
>   ITEMCLASS - SET id of item to value: 8549
>   ACTIONCLASS - now starting the execute() method
>   ACTIONCLASS - the set of items is EMPTY

As you can see, the items are created and their id's are being set! But unfortunately, the are not added to the set. Why is this?

What do I need to change about the line below to make it work as intented?

```
<input type="hidden" name="items.id" value="8549"/>
```

NOTE: If I change `Set` to `List` in my action class, this code works. But I really would like to work with a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: what is producing the logging? Code you have written, or the framework?

Comment: I added a few sysout statement in the relevant get/set methods and in the constructor of the Item class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is needed to use parentheses, like

```
<s:hidden name="items(%{#status.index}).id" value="8549"/>
```

Supposed it's used with iterator.

Annotations to use with the `Set` property

```
@Element(value = Item.class)
@Key(value = Integer.class)
@KeyProperty(value = "id") 
@CreateIfNull(value = true)
private Set<Item> items = new HashSet(0);
```

Comment: If I try that, I get the following exception: SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'items(0).id' on 'class com.company.items.manageItems: Error setting expression 'items(0).id' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@3cd372cb'

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: That is all there is. It's a 2 line log statement from the params interceptor. NOTE: your example does work for LISTS if I use square Brackets [ and ] instead of round brackets like ( and ). IT does not work for SETS in java, even if I use square brackets.

Comment: Use the typeconversion annotations in Struts, hope you know how it works in java.